# Is it legal to elide a non-trivial copy/move constructor in initialization?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer

Given this application:

```
#include <iostream>

struct X {
  X(int _x)                   { x = _x     + 1; }
  X(const X& that)            { x = that.x + 10; }
  X& operator=(const X& that) { x = that.x + 100; return *this; }
  X(X&& that)                 { x = that.x + 1000; }
  X& operator=(X&& that)      { x = that.x + 10000; return *this; }
  int x;
};

int main() {
  X a(1);
  std::cout << "a.x=" << a.x << std::endl;
  X b = 2;
  std::cout << "b.x=" << b.x << std::endl;
  X c = X(3);
  std::cout << "c.x=" << c.x << std::endl;
  X d = a;
  std::cout << "d.x=" << d.x << std::endl;
}
```

I expected the output to be:

```
a.x=2
b.x=1003
c.x=1004
d.x=12
```

Yet what I get is:

```
a.x=2
b.x=3
c.x=4
d.x=12
```

[Live example](http://rextester.com/IRR1416)

The only way to get my expected output is to compile with `-fno-elide-constructors` ([example](http://rextester.com/QKSH83987))

I thought the compiler may not elide stuff if doing so will affect the observed behavior, yet GCC, clang and MSVC seem to be doing just that.

Am I missing some general rule or is it specific to object initialization with a temporary?

Comment: dupe/related of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24559875/can-functions-be-optimized-away-if-they-have-side-effects) and/or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9253316/under-what-conditions-does-c-optimize-out-constructor-calls)

Comment: Also, `X b = 2;` is initialization, and never uses the assignment operator anyway.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Copy elision is allowed to happen even if it ignores side effects:

> `[class.copy]/31:` When certain criteria are met, an implementation is allowed to omit the copy/move construction of a class
>   object, **even if the constructor selected for the copy/move operation and/or the destructor for the object
>   have side effects**. [...]

A good general rule is to not write code which relies on copy/move constructor side effects, as you can easily get bitten by elision. This is particularly true in C++17, where certain cases of copy elision are mandatory.

Comment: To add to this, 12.8.31.3: "*when a temporary class object that has not been bound to a reference (12.2) would be copied/moved to a class object with the same cv-unqualified type, the copy/move operation can be omitted by constructing the temporary object directly into the target of the omitted copy/move*"

Answer (score 4):

To quote [the standard](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.copy.elision#constructor,copy,elision) 12.8.3:

> When certain criteria are met, an implementation is allowed to omit
>   the copy/move construction of a class object, **even if the constructor
>   selected for the copy/move operation and/or the destructor for the
>   object have side effects.**

<sup>(Emphasis mine)</sup>

This means that the compiler is allowed to elide the copy even if the copy has side effects. Which is exactly what's happening in your case.

Comment: It is 12.8.3 in the C++17 draft. I was asking about C+11. But I found it, 12.8.31.

Comment: @RustyX Yes, it's (kind of) in the same section, both in *12.8.3X*