# Constructor not called the expected number of times

Tags: c++, class, constructor

Here is the code which causes a problem:

```
class Base
{
public:
    virtual void fun()
    {
        cout<<"Base";
    }
};
class Der:public Base
{
    Base &pb;
public:
    Der(Base&b):pb(b){}
    virtual void fun()
    {
        cout<<"Der...";
        pb.fun();
    }
};
int main()
{
    Der(Der(Base())).fun();
    return 0;
}
```

Run this code,and the result shows "Der...Base..."! This is so amazing, I can't figure it out why the result is not "Der...Der...Base" which is logically right?!
  Then I replace the member in class Der `Base&pb` with `Base*pb` and change the code into legal, finnaly the output is right which is "Der...Der...Base"!
  I debug the code and find that when I use `Base&pb`, the constructor of Der only ran once while use `Base*pb`, the constructor ran twice correctly!
   Any one who can explain to me what had happened and why?

Comment: This code does not compile for me with multiple compilers and against both the C++03 and C++11 standards.

Comment: @DavidHammen: Indeed, it's trying to bind a temporary to a non-const _lvalue_ reference. One mainstream compiler supports that as an "extension". Conformant compilers require you to add `const` to the `Der` constructor argument and both `fun` functions.

Comment: The original title of this question was "Some Problems Of Implemention In Decorator Pattern". I think that this is perhaps a better description of the intent of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Der(Der(Base())).fun()` expression the inner `Der(Base())` yields an `rvalue` - the compiler optimizes the code by using [copy elision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6383639/conditions-for-copy-elision) and removes unnecessary copying of objects.

Comment: actually, it's not optimization: the compiler seems to treat the outer code as a cast, so we've got 2 objects and not 3.

Comment: @Vlad as far as I know function-style casting isn't applicable to class types (to avoid ambiguity such as this, I suppose).

Comment: @Vlad: It is a copy-elision optimisation. Unless there's a suitable conversion operator, casting between class types creates a new object using the appropriate conversion (or copy) constructor.

Comment: @icepack: function-style casting is applicable to all object types, and has the same effect as `static_cast`.

Comment: @MikeSeymour So how does the compiler choose whether `Der(Base())` should be the call to constructor of `Der` or should be the cast of `Base()` to `Der`?

Comment: @icepack: There's no such thing as a "call to constructor", although some people use that term to describe a function-style cast. `Der(Base())` is a cast from `Base` to `Der`, which in this case is performed using the conversion constructor.

Comment: @MikeSeymour I see. In this case compiler is smart enough to converge these 2 possibilities into 1, thus eliminating the ambiguity. Good to know. This, however, is different from normal cast - here 2 objects are created - `Base` and `Der`; this doesn't happen with `static_cast`, for example.

Comment: @icepack: I don't know what you mean by a "normal" cast. The copy can be elided when using either function-style or `static_cast`, since both styles of cast are equivalent for object types - [example](http://ideone.com/MFiEsu). (Note that I had to add `const` here and there, since the posted code incorrectly tries to bind a temporary to a non-const reference).

Comment: @MikeSeymour Yes, copy elision comes to the rescue, but that's not really related to the casting itself. My point is that `static_cast` never creates new object, while function-style cast do creates it in this case -> these 2 types of casts are not completely equivalent.

Comment: @icepack: `static_cast` *does* create a new object (when not elided), and for object types is exactly equivalent to a function-style cast. The C++ standard is quite clear on this: 5.2.3 defines a function-style cast with one parameter as equivalent to a C-style cast; 5.4 defines a C-style cast in terms of `static_cast`, `reinterpret_cast` and `const_cast` (with a few exceptions that only apply to pointers); and of those, only `static_cast` is applicable to object types.

Comment: Thank for your answer! The Der class multiple construct was elided by different compiler. So I decide to replace the &operator with pointer operator to avoid these strange problems.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the @icepack's answer and the following discussion in the comments (summary: the code `Der(der)` is a cast, which may or may not be realized using constructor; in your case it's not), a workaround for you: you should make your intention clear by not using the constructor.

I would rewrite your code into something like this:

```
class Base
{
public:
    virtual void fun()
    {
        cout<<"Base";
    }
};

class Der:public Base
{
    Base &pb;
    Der(Base& b) : pb(b) {}
public:
    static Der Decorate(Base&& b){ return Der(b); }
    virtual void fun()
    {
        cout<<"Der...";
        pb.fun();
    }
};

int main()
{
    Der::Decorate(Der::Decorate(Base())).fun();
    return 0;
}
```

([outputs: Der...Der...Base](http://ideone.com/VY3KrW)).

---

Changing the code to accept the pointer [is easy](http://ideone.com/vRuU4Q):

```
class Base
{
public:
    virtual void fun()
    {
        cout << "Base";
    }
};

class Der : public Base
{
    Base* pb;
    Der(Base* b) : pb(b) {}
public:
    static Der Decorate(Base* b){ return Der(b); }
    virtual void fun()
    {
        cout << "Der...";
        pb->fun();
    }
};

int main()
{
    Der::Decorate(&Der::Decorate(&Base())).fun();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13447109/when-constructor-or-type-cast-happens I posted today,and I find these problems are caused by compiler optimization.Thanks for your modification on the original code. But I'd like using pointer to replace the &operator to avoid this.Because I want to use the statements like "Der(&Der(&Base()));".

Comment: @Florian: note that in my old code, `Der(b)` in `static Der Decorate` couldn't possibly be optimized out, since there is no implicit downcast `Base -> Der`. So that code should work in any compiler.