# when constructor or type cast happens?

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are copy elision and return value optimization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12953127/what-are-copy-elision-and-return-value-optimization)

According to the question asked yesterday, I wrote a simple test code:

```
class A
{
public:
    A(int)
    {
        cout<<"constructor\n";
    }
    A(const A&)
    {
        cout<<"copy constructor\n";
    }
};

int main()
{
    A(0);
    cout<<"------------------------\n";
    A(A(0));
    cout<<"------------------------\n";
    A(A(A(0)));
    cout<<"------------------------\n";
    A(A(A(A(0))));
    cout<<"------------------------\n";
    A(A(A(A(A(0)))));
    cout<<"------------------------\n";
    return 0;
}
```

the outputs:

```
constructor
------------------------
constructor
------------------------
constructor
copy constructor
------------------------
constructor
copy constructor
------------------------
constructor
copy constructor
copy constructor
------------------------
```

So it's very strange to make it clear when the construtor called or the type cast happens, could anyone try to explain this ?

Comment: At worst each object constructor will be called, rest isn't really specified, since its all up to compiler to optimize

Comment: It is strange your compiler isn't eliding all or nothing.

Comment: The compiler I use is "Visual Studio 2010", is this problem caused by the compiler optimization or the semantic of C++ ?

Comment: [See this page.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_elision) On GCC it elides all of them (no copy constructor is called).

Comment: It's worth noting that in all of these, no type casts are done. There are two constructors, one taking an `int`, and one taking a `const A&` (which is the copy constructor). Even if no eliding was done, there would be no type casting. Just different constructors taking different parameters begin called.

Comment: @Cornstalks `A(0)` I believe is considered an explicit conversion which calls the copy constructor. You can also write it as `(A)0` or `static_cast<A>(0)`.

Comment: yes, you're right! I test the code with gcc4.4.3 and find that the constructor is only called once no matter how many "A(A(...))" were added,thanks!